# How can I ADD form values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

this is the code i came up with but all it does is this 1+1=11 i need it to do 1+1=2.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.form1.quantity.value;
  two = document.form1.price.value;
  c = one + two 
  document.form1.total.value = (c);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
Quantity: <input name="quantity" id="quantity" size="10">Price: <input name="price" id="price" size="10"><br>
Total: <input name="total" size="10" readonly=true><br>
<input onclick="startCalc();" onmouseout="stopCalc()" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

of course this is a really simple form, but you get the idea
please help me tell what i'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt()` to convert the string to an integer.

```
c = parseInt(one, 10) + parseInt(two, 10)
```

Comment: The second parameter, 10, is the base (i.e. base-10, decimal). While it's the default base, it's good to specify it anyway, and jslint will complain if you don't.

Comment: YES! it worked your the best! i'm fairly new to javascript so thats why i make dumb mistakes ;)

Comment: Isn't the `+one + +two` notation simpler?

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
c = parseInt(one,10) + parseInt(two, 10);
```

Comment: close, but don't forget the radix parameter or you can get some odd results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the price values to numeric.

use parseFloat for price since it can have decimal values.

use parseInt with the radix.

e,g:

```
function calc(){
  one = parseInt(document.form1.quantity.value, 10);
  two = parseFloat(document.form1.price.value);
  c = one + two 
  document.form1.total.value = (c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` to convert a string to a number (integer or float)

```
c = +one + +two;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  one = document.form1.quantity.value/1;
  two = document.form1.price.value/1;
```